# My code causes a StackOverflowError even with a base case

Tags: java

I'm writing a class that is intended to recursively trace through a lower and upper bound and sum all the values in between by returning to the lower value after going to the upper value. For example the call

System.out.println(sum(2, 5));

should return 23 because that is the sum of 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2.

The following is my code for this problem. Even with a base case, I still get a StackOverflowError due to the recursive calls on Lines 15 and 17.

```
public static int sum(int lower, int upper)
{
    int total = (upper - lower) + (upper - lower) + 1;
    return sum(lower, upper, total);
}

public static int sum(int lower, int upper, int total)
{
    if (lower < upper)
        return lower + sum(lower + 1, upper, total - 1);
    else if (lower == upper)
        return lower + sum(lower - 1, upper, total - 1);
    else if (total == 0)
        return 0;
    return 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println(sum(2, 5));
}
```

Can someone help me identify the reason for the StackOverflow and then correct it?

Comment: Use a Debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: This is an infinite recursion.... lower never gets bigger than upper.

Comment: If the solution below solves your problem, you may want to accept the solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, `lower` is 2 and `upper` is 5.

```
if (lower < upper)
    return lower + sum(lower + 1, upper, total - 1);
```

This condition is true, so you call `sum` with `lower==3` and `upper==5`.
This will call `sum` with `lower==4` and `upper==5`.
This will call `sum` with `lower==5` and `upper==5`.

This time you hit

```
else if (lower == upper)
    return lower + sum(lower - 1, upper, total - 1);
```

This will call `sum` with `lower==4` and `upper==5`. Again.

This gives you an infinite recursion. As soon as `lower` gets up to `upper`, you reduce it by one, so it keeps flipping up and down by 1.

*How do you fix it?*

If you must do this by recursion, you could simply write something like this:

```
public static int sum(int lower, int upper) {
    // shouldn't happen, but in case you pass in weird arguments
    if (lower > upper) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (lower==upper) {
        return upper;
    }
    return 2*lower + sum(lower+1, upper);
}
```

So for `sum(2,5)` you get

```
sum(2,5) = 2*2 + sum(3,5)
         = 2*2 + 3*3 + sum(4,5)
         = 2*2 + 2*3 + 2*4 + sum(5,5)
         = 2*2 + 2*3 + 2*4 + 5
         = 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2
```

Comment: OP could solve this by adding a flag which indicates whether it's ascending or not. e.g. `sum(int lower, int upper, int total, boolean isAscending)`

Comment: Thanks so much for this response. It really helped me out a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. There's an accept-answer button around here somewhere.